# NetworkX read_shp not working with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm trying to read a shapefile in a directory (with .shx, .dbf, .cpg). In Python 2.7 it's working correctly while in Python 3 it won't get past the `read_shp()` function.

Any workaround?

```
def render_network():
directory  = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'files/2017-10-24/2017-10-24.shp')

G = nx.read_shp(directory, simplify=False)

print("NODES: " + str(len(G.nodes())))
print("EDGES: " + str(len(G.edges())))
print(nx.is_directed(G))
```

Error/ Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /shapefile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/network/views.py", line 105, in geojson_to_shp
    render_network()
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/network/views.py", line 112, in render_network
    G = nx.read_shp(directory, simplify=False)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py", line 71, in read_shp
    for f in lyr:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Layer'
```

Comment: What's the `networkx.__version__`? In 1.9.1, the said line `for f in lyr:` in nx_shp.py does not exist anymore. Maybe you need to update networkx for your Python 3.5 installation.

Comment: @Jeronimo I updated it and it's still the same error. `>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("networkx").version
'1.11'
`

Comment: @Jeronimo could I be pointing at some wrong networkx? I checked at git though, nx_shp.py is there and the line `for f in lyr` too

Comment: Ah no, sorry, you're right, it's the other way round, the 1.11 now has that line.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when i was using the networkx-3.1.

Then i found the following note in the networkx official api document:

```
Removed after version 2.6: Read_shp deprecated and will be removed in NetworkX 3.0. See [networkx geospatial](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/auto_examples/index.html#geospatial)
```

So, if you need to use read_shp features, you can only use networks before 2.6 or 2.6