# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'read_shp'

Tags: python, anaconda, networkx

Trying to read shp-file using networkX module like this:
`G=nx.read_shp(r'path\to\test.shp')`.

This results in error: `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'read_shp'`

NetworkX (3.2.1) is installed in Ananconda env (python 3.12.0).
Results from runnning `print(dir(nx))`does not include 'read_shp' either.

Have I missed something in the installation of the module? Any ideas for solving this?

Thankful for any help

Comment: Looks like the latest version of networkx doesn't have that function anymore.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77101543/494134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.read_shp` was deprecated in [2.6](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/release_2.6.html#deprecations) (*see [GH4298](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/4298) for details*).

> Functions for reading and writing shapefiles are provided in `NetworkX` versions `<3.0`. However, **we recommend that you use the following libraries** when working with geospatial data (including reading and writing shapefiles) : GeoPandas, PySal, ..

You can use [`gdf_to_nx`](https://%60https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/generated/momepy.gdf_to_nx.html) (`conda install -c conda-forge momepy`) :

```
import momepy
from momepy.datasets import get_path
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx

# In your config, you can pass the shapefile path to `read_file`
streets = gpd.read_file(get_path("bubenec"), layer="streets")

G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(streets, approach="primal")

nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for alternative method, this runs fine!